# Binary Serialization of std::bitset

Tags: c++, stl, binary, bitset

`std::bitset` has a `to_string()` method for serializing as a `char`-based string of `1`s and `0`s. Obviously, this uses a single 8 bit `char` for *each* bit in the bitset, making the serialized representation 8 times longer than necessary.
I want to store the bitset in a binary representation to save space. The `to_ulong()` method is relevant only when there are less than 32 bits in my bitset. I have hundreds.
I'm not sure I want to use `memcpy()`/`std::copy()` on the object (address) itself, as that assumes the object is a POD.

The API does not seem to provide a handle to the internal array representation from which I could have taken the address.

I would also like the option to deserialize the bitset from the binary representation.

How can I do this?

Comment: Big Endian or Little Endian?  Makes a big difference (a.k.a. bit ordering)?

Comment: Not really. If the bitset is saved as an array of chars, there is no direct influence for Endianess.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a possible approach based on explicit creation of an `std::vector<unsigned char>` by reading/writing one bit at a time...

```
template<size_t N>
std::vector<unsigned char> bitset_to_bytes(const std::bitset<N>& bs)
{
    std::vector<unsigned char> result((N + 7) >> 3);
    for (int j=0; j<int(N); j++)
        result[j>>3] |= (bs[j] << (j & 7));
    return result;
}

template<size_t N>
std::bitset<N> bitset_from_bytes(const std::vector<unsigned char>& buf)
{
    assert(buf.size() == ((N + 7) >> 3));
    std::bitset<N> result;
    for (int j=0; j<int(N); j++)
        result[j] = ((buf[j>>3] >> (j & 7)) & 1);
    return result;
}
```

Note that to call the de-serialization template function `bitset_from_bytes` the bitset size `N` must be specified in the function call, for example

```
std::bitset<N> bs1;
...
std::vector<unsigned char> buffer = bitset_to_bytes(bs1);
...
std::bitset<N> bs2 = bitset_from_bytes<N>(buffer);
```

If you really care about speed one solution that would gain something would be doing a loop unrolling so that the packing is done for example one byte at a time, but even better is just to write your own bitset implementation that doesn't hide the internal binary representation instead of using `std::bitset`.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question for completeness.

Apparently, there is no simple *and* portable way of doing this.

For simplicity (though not efficiency), I ended up using `to_string`, and then creating consecutive 32-bit bitsets from all 32-bit chunks of the string (and the remainder*), and using `to_ulong` on each of these to collect the bits into a binary buffer.
This approach leaves the bit-twiddling to the STL itself, though it is probably not the most efficient way to do this.

***  *Note that since `std::bitset` is templated on the total bit-count, the remainder bitset needs to use some simple template meta-programming arithmetic.*

Comment: Your solution is for sure several times slower than just doing the serialization yourself by reading out the bits...

Comment: Perhaps. I'll have to test that.

Comment: With g++ naively packing the bits into an array of unsigned char is a bit slower than just calling `std::bitset::to_string` (and becomes faster than `to_string` if done with hand-unrolling 8 bits at a time). Note that with your solution after calling `to_string` you have still to do the splitting, rebuilding all the bitsets, callint `to_ulong` on them...

Comment: What do you mean when you say "naively packing the bits into an array of unsigned char"? Testing each bit &ing and shifting? By hand unrolling you mean doing the loop with skips of 8 and explicitly Testing each bit &ing and shifting?

Comment: The naive loop is `for (int j=0; j<N; j++) result[j>>3] |= (bs[j] << (j&7));`. The unrolled one computes and stores one byte at a time.

Comment: Thanks 6502. If you write it as a full answer I will happily accept it.

Answer (score 1):

**edit:** The following does not work as intended. Appearently, "binary format" actually means "ASCII representation of binary".

---

You should be able to write them to a `std::ostream` using `operator<<`. It says [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/bitset/):

> [Bitsets] can also be directly inserted and extracted from streams in binary format.

Comment: Yes, I saw this comment. In my bitset implementation, operator<<() just calls to_string(), so I don't know what that means? Is there some other Standard ref. where this might be mentioned?

Comment: Right, I just tested it and it also doesn't work. I will update my answer. Sorry

Comment: Yes, I just checked the Standard and that's basically what it says.

Comment: @user634618 This is very late, but I thought I would add it in for anyone else looking at this thread. The << operator DOES work for writing a std::bitset<> to an std::ostream.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by guys at gamedev.net, one can try using [boost::dynamic_bitset](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html) since it allows access to internal representation of bitpacked data.

Comment: This answer isn't much use without a code example. Looking at the docs, it only appears to provide bytes in chunks of `unsigned long` (unless you specify a different template parameter) so I think you'd still need a loop, possibly two nested loops.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see an obvious way other than converting to a string and doing your own serialization of the string that groups chunks of 8 characters into a single serialized byte.

EDIT: Better is to just iterate over all the bits with `operator[]` and manually serialize it.

Comment: I wanted to avoid manual bit-twiddling, as the representation is already coded in the internal continuous array.

Answer (score 0):

this might help you, it's a little example of various serialization types.
I added bitset and raw bit values, that can be used like the below.

(all examples at https://github.com/goblinhack/simple-c-plus-plus-serializer)

```
class BitsetClass {
public:
    std::bitset<1> a;
    std::bitset<2> b;
    std::bitset<3> c;

    unsigned int d:1; // need c++20 for default initializers for bitfields
    unsigned int e:2;
    unsigned int f:3;
    BitsetClass(void) { d = 0; e = 0; f = 0; }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out,
                                    Bits<const class BitsetClass & > const m
    {
        out << bits(my.t.a);
        out << bits(my.t.b);
        out << bits(my.t.c);

        std::bitset<6> s(my.t.d | my.t.e << 1 | my.t.f << 3);
        out << bits(s);

        return (out);
    }

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &in,
                                    Bits<class BitsetClass &> my)
    {
        std::bitset<1> a;
        in >> bits(a);
        my.t.a = a;

        in >> bits(my.t.b);
        in >> bits(my.t.c);
        std::bitset<6> s;
        in >> bits(s);

        unsigned long raw_bits = static_cast<unsigned long>(s.to_ulong());
        my.t.d = raw_bits & 0b000001;
        my.t.e = (raw_bits & 0b000110) >> 1;
        my.t.f = (raw_bits & 0b111000) >> 3;

        return (in);
    }
};
```