# What's the best way to store binary

Tags: c++

Ive recently implemented Hoffman compression in c++, if I were to store the results as binary it would take up a lot more space as each 1 and 0 is a character. Alternatively I was thinking maybe I could break the binary into sections of 8 and put characters in the text file, but that would kinda be annoying (so hopefully that can be avoided). My question here is what is the best way to store binary in a text file in terms of character efficietcy?

Comment: Why would you store each 1 or 0 as a `char`? You'd usually store 8 of them together as individual bits of a [byte](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte).

Comment: Use serialization. Text files are awful ways to store data if you're trying to keep things small.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding - although storing it in binary would be more efficient. Why are you trying to save this as text?

Comment: You want to store binary in a text file.  You could store it as base-16 (hexadecimal), or base-64, or base-85, or quite a few others.  Which is most suitable depends on your needs.

Comment: This may help or at least give you some ideas: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251403/binary-serialization-of-stdbitset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251403/binary-serialization-of-stdbitset)

Comment: "Hoffman" or "Huffman"?

Comment: I'm not sure if specified text file because a text file format is required or if this was just your choice of words. Binary data can be written directly to a file. Do you require a text file format specifically?

Answer (score 1):

[To recap the comments...]

> My question here is what is the best way to store binary in a text file in terms of character efficiently?

If you can store the data as-is, then do so (in other words, do not use any encoding; simply save the raw bytes).

If you need to store the data within a text file (for instance as a paragraph or as a quoted string), then you have many ways of doing so. For instance, base64 is a very common one, but there are many others.